# Unreliable behaviour in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, bluebird, knex.js

I have a Node.js application that, upon initialisation, reads two tables from an SQL database and reconstructs their relationship in memory. They're used for synchronously looking up data that changes (very) infrequently.

**Problem**: Sometimes I can't access the data, even though the application reports successfully loading it.

**Code:**

**constants.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ready: function () { return false; }
};

var log = sysLog('core', 'constants')
  , Geo = require('../models/geo.js');

var _ready     = false
  , _countries = []
  , _carriers  = [];

function reload() {
  _ready = false;

  var index = Object.create(null);

  return Geo.Country.find().map(function (country) {
      var obj = country.toPlainObject()
        , id  = obj.id;

      delete obj.id;
      index[id] = obj;

      return Object.freeze(obj);
    }).then(function (countries) {
      log.debug('Loaded ' + countries.length + ' countries');

      _countries = countries;

      return Geo.Carrier.Descriptor.find().map(function (carrier) {
          var obj = carrier.toPlainObject();

          if (obj.country) {
            obj.country = index[obj.country];
          }

          return Object.freeze(obj);
        }).then(function (carriers) {
          log.debug('Loaded ' + carriers.length + ' carriers');

          _carriers = carriers;
        });
    }).finally(function () {
      _ready = true;
    });
}

reload().catch(function (err) {
  log.crit({ message: 'Could not load constants', reason: err });
  process.exit(-42);
}).done();

module.exports = {
  reload    : reload,

  ready     : function () { return _ready; },

  countries : function () { return _countries; },
  carriers  : function () { return _carriers; }
};
```

**utils.js**

```
var log       = sysLog('core', 'utils')
  , constants = require('./constants');

module.exports = {
  getCountryByISO: function(iso) {
    if (!iso) {
      return;
    }

    if ('string' != typeof iso) {
      throw new Error('getCountryByISO requires a string');
    }

    if (!constants.ready()) {
      throw new UnavailableError('Try again in a few seconds');
    }

    switch (iso.length) {
      case 2:
        return _.findWhere(constants.countries(), { 'iso2' : iso.toUpperCase() });

      case 3:
        return _.findWhere(constants.countries(), { 'iso3' : iso.toUpperCase() });

      default:
        throw new Error('getCountryByISO requires a 2 or 3 letter ISO code');
    }
  },

  getCarrierByCode: function(code) {
    if (!code) {
      return;
    }

    if ('string' != typeof code) {
      throw new Error('getCarrierByCode requires a string');
    }

    if (!constants.ready()) {
      throw new UnavailableError('Try again in a few seconds');
    }

    return _.findWhere(constants.carriers(), { 'code' : code });
  },

  getCarrierByHandle: function(handle) {
    if (!handle) {
      return;
    }

    if ('string' != typeof handle) {
      throw new Error('getCarrierByHandle requires a string');
    }

    if (!constants.ready()) {
      throw new UnavailableError('Try again in a few seconds');
    }

    return _.findWhere(constants.carriers(), { 'handle' : handle });
  }
};
```

Use case

```
if (data.handle) {
  carrier = utils.getCarrierByHandle(data.handle);

  if (_.isEmpty(carrier)) {
    throw new InternalError('Unknown carrier', { handle: data.handle });
  }
}
```

**What's going on:** All errors are logged; as soon as I see an error (i.e. "Unknown carrier") in the logs, I check the SQL database to see if it should've been recognised. That has always been the case so far, so I check the debug log to see if data was loaded. I always see "Loaded X countries" and "Loaded Y carriers" with correct values and no sign of "Could not load constants" or any other kind of trouble.

This happens around 10% of the time I start the application and the problem persists (i.e. didn't seem to go away after 12+ hours) and seems to occur regardless of input, leading me to think that the data isn't referenced correctly.

**Questions:**

1. **Is there something wrong in constants.js** or am I doing something very obviously wrong? I've tried setting it up for cyclical loading (even though I am not aware of that happening in this case).
2. **Why can't I (sometimes) access my data?**
3. **What can I do to figure out what's wrong?**
4. **Is there any way I can work around this? Is there anything else I could to achieve the desired behaviour?** Hard-coding the data in **constants.js** is excluded.

**Additional information:**

- `constants.reload()` is never actually called from outside of **constants.js**.
- **constants.js** is *require*d only in **utils.js**.
- **utils.js** is *require*d in **app.js** (application entry); all files *require*d before it do not *require* it.
- SQL access is done through an in-house library built on top of knex.js and bluebird; so far it's been very stable.

**Versions:**

**Node.js** v0.10.33

**underscore** 1.7.0

**bluebird** 2.3.11

**knex** 0.6.22

Comment: It looks like that would happen if the handle being requested is empty, I assume your `Unknown carrier` messages log a valid `data.handle` value?

Comment: Yes, that value is also validated to be non-empty. I'll edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> constants.reload() is never actually called from outside of
>   constants.js.

That's your issue. `constants.reload()` reads from a database, which is an aysnchronous process. Node's `require()` is a synchronous process. At the time `constants.js` is required in `utils.js` and the `module.exports` value is returned, your database query is still running. And at whatever point in time that `app.js` reaches the point where it calls a method from the utils module, that query could *still* be running, resulting in the error.

You could say that requiring utils.js has the side-effect of requiring constants.js, which has the side-effect of executing a database query, which has the side-effect of concurrently modifying the free variables `_countries` and `_carriers`.

Initialize `_countries` and `_carriers` as unresolved promises. Have `reload()` resolve them. Make the utils.js api async.

promises.js:

```
// ...

var Promise = require('bluebird');

var countriesResolve
  , carriersResolve;

var _ready     = false
  , _countries = new Promise(function (resolve) {
      countriesResolve = resolve;
  })
  , _carriers  = new Promise(function (resolve) {
      carriersResolve = resolve;
  });

function reload() {
  _ready = false;

  var index = Object.create(null);

  return Geo.Country.find().map(function (country) {
      // ...
    }).then(function (countries) {
      log.debug('Loaded ' + countries.length + ' countries');

      countriesResolve(countries);

      return Geo.Carrier.Descriptor.find().map(function (carrier) {
          // ...
        }).then(function (carriers) {
          log.debug('Loaded ' + carriers.length + ' carriers');

          carriersResolve(carriers);
        });
    }).finally(function () {
      _ready = true;
    });
}

reload().catch(function (err) {
  log.crit({ message: 'Could not load constants', reason: err });
  process.exit(-42);
}).done();

module.exports = {
  reload    : reload,

  ready     : function () { return _ready; },

  countries : function () { return _countries; },
  carriers  : function () { return _carriers; }
};
```

utils.js

```
getCarrierByHandle: function(handle) {
  // ...

  return constants.carriers().then(function (carriers) {
    return _.findWhere(carriers, { 'handle' : handle });
  });
}
```

Use case:

```
utils.getCarrierByHandle(data.handle).then(function (carrier) {
  if (_.isEmpty(carrier)) {
    throw new InternalError('Unknown carrier', { handle: data.handle });
  }
}).then(function () {
  // ... next step in application logic
});
```

This design will also eliminate the need for a `ready` method.

Alternatively, you could call `constants.reload()` on initialization and hang all possibly-dependent operations until it completes. This approach would also obsolete the `ready` method.

> What can I do to figure out what's wrong?

You could have analyzed your logs and observed that "Loaded X countries" and "Loaded Y carriers" were sometimes written after "Unknown carrier", helping you realize that the success of `utils.getCarrierByHandle()` was a race condition.

Comment: I've guarded the calls in **utils.js** with `constants.ready()`. Also, I've mentioned that the problem persists (even after 12+ hours), so at least part of it isn't strictly related to the time it takes to perform the queries.

Comment: Does `throw new UnavailableError('Try again in a few seconds');` get logged?

Comment: Further clarification: this entire constants system is required to behave in a synchronous manner. I can afford a few *UnavailableError*s while it's loading but apparently something breaks in a subtle way even after it's done loading.

Comment: All errors end up in a log. I have observed the `throw new UnavailableError('Try again in a few seconds')` in the logs, in short bursts, as expected during normal operation.

Comment: Errors should never be "as expected during normal operation." You should design your system to be error free. An `UnavailableError` should be unnecessary in a system that utilizes promises (barring long-running network requests where a service would actually be unavailable).

Comment: While I am responsible for system design, requirements aren't very debatable; a change in architecture wouldn't be justified at the moment, I'm interested if there are any bugs in my code or if there's a problem with one of the components.

Comment: The equivalent in bluebird would be just the same, however `.defer` is not in primary documentation because its use is deprecated, for a good reason as it makes people use unnecessarily complicated and brittle code as you did here.

Comment: "unnecessarily complicated"? He can "call constants.reload() on initialization" if he wants to keep a sync API. "brittle code"? I consider race conditions "brittle," which my code is not subject to.

Comment: Updated to use bluebird's API. `.defer` is apparently too atrocious.

Comment: This isn't about which API or method is better. I really need the sync API, it's the reason why I have this problem in the first place.

Comment: "Alternatively, you could call constants.reload() on initialization and hang all possibly-dependent operations until it completes." [Then you can use the sync API.]

Answer (score 0):

```
}).finally(function () {
  _ready = true;
});
```

Code in a `finally` will always get called, regardless of if an error was thrown up the promise chain. Additionally, your `reload().catch(/* ... */)` clause will never be reached, because `finally` swallows the error.

`Geo.Country.find()` or `Geo.Carrier.Descriptor.find()` could throw an error, and `_ready` would still be set to `true`, and the problem of your countries and carriers not being set would persist.

This problem would not have occurred if you had designed your system without a `ready` call, as I described in my previous post. Hopefully this informs you that the issue here is really beyond `finally` swallowing a `catch`. The real issue is *relying on side-effects*; the modification of free variables results in brittle systems, especially when asynchrony is involved. I highly recommend against it.

Comment: I do `reload().catch(function (err) {` and call `process.exit()` in case there was an error. Would this not suffice?

Comment: Nevermind, just tried catching something after a `finally`. `catch` always gets called. http://jsfiddle.net/57y5624c/1/

Comment: Knex.js doesn't have a `find` method, which leads me to imply that you designed `Geo.Country.find()` and `Geo.Carrier.Descriptor.find()`. How do those work? An error might be swallowed in there, and/or you might be returning an empty array in the case of failure.

Comment: Yes, we have a model library built on top of knex. We use it everywhere, it wouldn't make sense for this to be an isolated incident. Also, I checked the logs for "Loaded X countries" and "Loaded Y carriers" which suggests the SQL part is functioning as intended.

Comment: Is "Loaded X countries" and "Loaded Y carriers" logged after or before "Unknown carrier"?

Comment: I'll get back to you on that. "Unknown carrier" certainly appears a lot of times after loading in the erroneous scenario, I haven't logged them to the same output to see if any appears before, which would indeed be problematic.

Comment: I've added a `log.debug` instruction in the **utils.js** functions to notify whenever they return an empty result and what parameter they were called with. None of the calls go through before the "Loaded X ...", so the `constants.ready()` guard seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var log = sysLog('core', 'constants');
var Geo = require('../models/geo.js');
var index;
var _countries; 
var _carriers;

function reload() {
  index = Object.create(null);
  _countries = Geo.Country.find().map(function (country) {
    var obj = country.toPlainObject();
    var id  = obj.id;

    delete obj.id;
    index[id] = obj;

    return Object.freeze(obj);
  });

  _carriers = _countries.then(function(countries) {
    return Geo.Carrier.Descriptor.find().map(function (carrier) {
      var obj = carrier.toPlainObject();

      if (obj.country) {
        obj.country = index[obj.country];
      }

      return Object.freeze(obj);
    });
  });
  return _carriers;
}

reload().done();

module.exports = {
  reload    : reload,
  countries : function () { return _countries; },
  carriers  : function () { return _carriers; }
};
```

Comment: Okay; I see what you meant by "unnecessarily complicated" now. I like your approach better.

Comment: @Jackson Another problem is that deferreds need to be manually rejected which is easy to forget, sometimes it may even require mixing the synchronous try catch statement along with promise error handler to cover all your bases and never have a situation where the deferred is left pending indefinitely

Comment: Aside from the fact that this removes the `ready` check and all possibility of doing synchronous look-ups, is there anything I'm missing?